# How to quickly calculate what points are within a given distance of my point

Tags: java, math, geometry, coordinates

I have a large number of Longitude and Latitudes and I want to quickly find out which ones are within say a 5km radius of a certain Longitude Latitude.

Instead of using a datastructure (Which would be overkill), I should be able to perform n do products very quickly. I've just done something wrong and can't seem to see what.

I have been trying to implement this in Java:

```
        final List<CoOrds> coOrds = Create20x20Grid();

        // Determine point X (centre of earth)
        final Vector2 X = new Vector2(0,0);

        // My CoOrd I want to check
        final double srclon = coOrds.get(0).getLongitude();
        final double srclat = coOrds.get(0).getLatitude();

        final Vector2 A = new Vector2(srclon, srclat, true);

        final double brng = 0;
        final double d = 5;
        final double R = 6371.1;
        double dist = 0;

        dist = d / R; // convert dist to angular distance in radians

        final double lat1 = Math.toRadians(srclat);
        final double lon1 = Math.toRadians(srclon);

        final double lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(dist)+ Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(brng));
        double lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(lat1),Math.cos(dist) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2));

        // normalise to -180..+180º
        lon2 = (lon2 + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;


        //Create another point which is the distance is d away from your point
        final Vector2 B = new Vector2(Math.toDegrees(lon2),Math.toDegrees(lat2), true);

        // Create a vector from X->A
        final Vector2 X_A = new Vector2((A.getX() - X.getX()),(A.getY() - X.getY()));
        // Create a vector from X->B
        final Vector2 X_B = new Vector2((B.getX() - X.getX()),(B.getY() - X.getY()));

        // Normalize XA
        final Vector2 nX_A = X_A.normalize();
        // Normalize XB
        final Vector2 nX_B = X_B.normalize();

        // Calculate the Dot Product
        final Double Alpha = nX_A.dot(nX_B);

        int count = 0;
        for (final CoOrds c : coOrds) {

            final Vector2 P = c.getPosition();
            final Vector2 X_P = new Vector2((P.getX() - X.getX()),(P.getY() - X.getY()));

            final Vector2 nX_P = X_P.normalize());
            final Double Beta = nX_A.dot(nX_P);

            if (Beta < Alpha) {
                System.out.println(count + " -- " + Beta + " : " + Alpha);
                count++;
            }

        }


        System.out.println("Number of CoOrds within Distance : " + count);
```

The new point P is correct as I've loaded it into Google Maps, but I am not entirely sure if I have the calculations correct.

I have created a custom Vector2 class, which stores the Longitude and Latitude. It also coverts them to Cartesian:

```
    private void convertSphericalToCartesian(final double latitude, final double longitude) {

    x = (earthRadius * Math.cos(latitude) * Math.cos(longitude)) ;
    y = (earthRadius * Math.cos(latitude) * Math.sin(longitude)) ;
}
```

The Dot Product:

```
    public double dot(final Vector2 v2) {

    return ((getX() * v2.getX()) + (getY() * v2.getY()));

}
```

The Normalize:

```
    public Vector2 normalize() {

    final double num2 = (getX() * getX()) + (getY() * getY());
    final double num = 1d / Math.sqrt(num2);

    double a = x;
    double b = y;

    a *= num;
    b *= num;

    return new Vector2(a, b);
}
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated

I used this website: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
To help me calculate point B.

I used this website : http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/conversion-between-spherical-and-cartesian-coordinates-systems/
To help me transform Spherical CoOrdinates to Cartesian CoOrdinates.

Thanks

[EDIT]

The test case I am currently running is:

0-0-0

2-2-0

1-2-0

Where the above is a grid of 9 points. The point I am checking is "1". I expect it to return all the points "2". But it is returning all the points in the grid. I have manually checked the distances on Google Maps and it should only be returning the points "2".

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: What make you think there's something wrong with your code?

Comment: Are you asking how you can check where you code is correct or not?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. Basically I have set up a 20x20 test grid, where the distance between each point is 1km. When I select a point to see what points are within 1km it returns all 400. When it should infact return 8.

Comment: I am not 100% certain if it is because I have implemented the Math Forumulas incorrectly (Dot, Normalize etc) or if I am simply using the formula incorrectly.

Comment: @Sonil - That's good information.  Add it to your question so readers will know what your asking.  It would seem that your first step is to prove your formulas are correct.  Pick 2 points with a well-known answer (not all 400 - that's too hard!) and run your calculation.  If it works, you'll know the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments above, you're not sure if your formulae are accurate.

The first step is to figure that out.

Select a few well-known points on the globe (North Pole, South Pole, Greenwich UK, etc), and create a test case that invokes convertSphericaltoCartesian() with these coordinates.  Check the results and see if they make any sense.

Comment: The Vector2 class can accept a boolean which allows it to perform the convert to Cartesian. Vector2 A = new Vector2(srclon, srclat, true); This method then takes the Spherical CoOrdinates and converts them to Cartesian. I followed : http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/conversion-between-spherical-and-cartesian-coordinates-systems/

Comment: I then store the Cartesian CoOrdinates as X,Y in the Vector class. (Keeping the long lat just for my own reference)

Comment: ok, we all copy-paste code from the internet.  However, your code is not working, you're going to have to crawl through the code and find the flaw.  Developing this skill is just as critical as learning how to code.